# "mailto" of the current html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mailto

I'm trying to generate an email in client side out of the current html page (to be more precise a div named "inc" inside my page).
i'm stuck in the very first steps where i have this code:

```js
    function emailCurrentPage() {
    var htmlData = document.getElementById('inc').innerHTML;
    window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=" + document.title + "&body=" + htmlData;}
```

```html
    <a href="javascript:emailCurrentPage()">Mail this page!</a>
```

When I press the link nothing happens, when  debugging I **can** see the html code in "htmlData" variable.

Moreover, when I change the "htmlData" in the third row to some text like "bla bla" or even `<html><body></body></html>` the email is being opened normally.

What can be the reason for the `mailto` not to work with htmlData ?

One more little question. Do you think I am on the right way for sending an HTML page ? Because I'm afraid I won't be able later to convert the HTML code to be seen as HTML page in the email.

Comment: it might need url encoded and url lengths are really constrained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its definently not cool to call a JS function with href. You will also want to format your mailto: link.

```html
<button onclick="javascript:emailCurrentPage()">Mail this page!</button>


<script>
function emailCurrentPage() {
var htmlData = document.getElementById('inc').innerHTML;
window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject="' + document.title + '"&body=' + htmlData;}</script>


<main id="inc">
  Some text here
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not cool to href a function. Try adding onclick= "javascript:emailCurrentPage()" and the href ="#" to that  tag